# Repetitive optional parameters in route

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I’ve been looking for a solution that would allow me using multiple optional parameters in a route.

Something like
`/product/{category?*}/{productname}`

Let’s say I have 1 product that belongs to 4 categories and a second product that belongs to 7 categories. These categories are in a parent-child relation (it’s a tree). I would like to see the whole category family in the url when I go to the product page.

For example, the first product url would look like this:

[www.myshop.com/product/main1/sub1/sub11/sub111/myproduct](http://www.myshop.com/product/main1/sub1/sub11/sub111/myproduct)

With the second product it would be:

[www.myshop.com/product/main2/sub2/sub22/sub222/sub2222/sub22222/sub222222/myproduct2](http://www.myshop.com/product/main2/sub2/sub22/sub222/sub2222/sub22222/sub222222/myproduct2)

Is there a solution that would allow behaviour like this?

Comment: This is a pretty bad idea!! The URL for product pages should simply be `product/{id}` or `product/{name}`.

Answer (score 2):

You can define your route by combining all the categories, as well as the product name into a single URL parameter. Try the following

```
<?php
// File web.php

Route::get('/product/{categoriesAndProduct}', function ($categoriesAndProduct) {
    dd($categoriesAndProduct);
    // output: main1/sub1/sub11/sub111/myproduct
})->where('categoriesAndProduct', '.*');
```

You will have then to write your own logic to ensure that:

- There are at least two values
- The last values matches an existing product
- All categories exist and in the right order
- The product belongs to those categories